# How can I generate a wordcloud using matplotlib, store it inside a variable send it and render it on a HTML page?

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, flask, word-cloud

## My python code

What i'm doing here is receiving a JSON by POST method, extracting a certain property from it to form a string. Afterwards I do generate a wordcloud using **matplotlib** library.

My goal is to somehow "generate" an image WITHOUT STORING IT ON MY SERVER, as I would think it's a variable or something alike that. And then "send" it to a HTML page and show it.

```
import json


@app.route('/wordcloud', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def wordcloud():
    print('****************************************')
    jsoncito = request.form['wordcloud']
    print('22222222222222222222222222222222222222222')
    jsonParaPasar = json.dumps(jsoncito)
    text = ""
    newjson = json.loads(request.form['wordcloud'])
    neww = ast.literal_eval(newjson)

for x in neww:
    text = text + x['respuesta'] + " "

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=480, height=480, margin=0).generate(text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.margins(x=10, y=10)
```

I read maybe I can turn it into a numpy array in order to send it, but I don't know how to turn that into a proper image!

Comment: Why use matplotlib? Why not directly send the wordcloud image?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I don't know what you mean by "directly send the wordcloud image" but I'm never generating a proper JPG or PNG image.

Comment: I mean you can let wordcloud generate the png image and forget about matplotlib, right?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yeah! I finally decided to do that instead, now I have to figure out how to dynamically change an image's source using flask syntax